# ST_Contains. Check for true/false in Python cursor

Tags: python, postgresql

I would like to create a list of toponyms, which are within some distance from a point. I have calculated a buffer (dbrows_transf_back) and now I am checking if toponyms from a gazetteer (dbrows_os) are within this buffer. If I get "True" as a result, I will append the toponym to the name_list. The problem is that I don't know how to catch true and false. When I print dbrows_contain I get [(False,)] or [(True,)]. I have tried `if dbrows_contains == 't':` `if dbrows_contains == '[(True,)]':` and `if dbrows_contains is True:`
I am not sure, what else I can do. Any ideas?

```
name_list = []
for j in dbrows_os:
    name = j[0]
    toponym = j[1]
    sql_intersect = "SELECT ST_Contains(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromEWKT('"+dbrows_transf_back+"'), 4326), ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromEWKT('"+toponym+"'),4326))"
    cur.execute(sql_intersect)
    dbrows_contains = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    if dbrows_contains is True:
        print "true"
        name_list.append(name)
```

Comment: Try, `dbrows_contains[0][0]==True`. I think there is a more elegant way, but that should work. That will convert [(True,)] to True. Or simply, `if dbrows_contains[0][0]: do_something` as the is True is redundant.

Comment: The reason for this is that [cursor.fetchall](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall) returns a list of tuples, so, the first [0] takes the first row/tuple in the returned list and the 2nd [0] takes the first returned column. There is only one, in your case, but you still need to index the tuple, or else you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @JohnBarça you've made my day! It works perfectly. Do you want to write your comment as an answer, so i can "accept" it?

Comment: Always nice to make someone's day. I have added a couple more things that might interest you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [cursor.fetchall](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall) you will see that the return value is a list containing many tuples, each tuple representing a row in the returned query (cursorset). So, in order to test for that a return value `[(True,)]` is true, you need to use double indexing, [0][0], once to return the first element of the list, and once to select the first element in the tuple, which will be True or False, which means that to test for True, you can just write:

```
if dbrows_contains[0][0]:
  do_something
```

You may, however, find that iterating over each row of the cursor is more efficient than cursor_fetch_all, ie,

```
for row in cursor:
    if row[0]:
       do_something
```

See, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861152/cursor-fetchall-vs-listcursor-in-python) for more information.

Finally, you can probably completely rewrite the logic, so that you only return rows where ST_Contains = 't', ie, by moving ST_Contains to the WHERE clause of your query, and then simply testing if the cursor.fetchall call exists. There are many ways to skin a cat :D.